# Notation for words with a common substring/factor

Tags: formal-languages

Let $A$ be an alphabet and $u,v\in A^{*}$ be words. If it exists $z, u', u'', v', v'' \in A^{*}$ such as: $u = u'zu'' $ and $v = v'zv''$ then $z$ is a *substring* (also known as *factor*) of both $u$ and $v$ (*i.e.* “common”).

Is there a fairly standard or acceptable *notation* to denote either:

- The predicate: “$u$ and $v$ have a common substring/factor”
- The set of substrings/factors commons to $u$ and $v$

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but, in my experience, "substring" is a _much_ more term than "factor" and that might help you find an answer.

Comment: Actually, I suspect there is no agreed-on notation for this. The [Wikipedia article on substrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) doesn't even give notation for "$x$ is a substring of $y$".